# Sinan and Erlide usable together?

Tags: erlang, build-automation, erlide

Has anyone successfully managed to get Eclipse+Erlide and Sinan (or EPM or something I ought to have heard of but haven´t) to co-exist? I get problems when I generate a Sinan directory structure and then try to import it into Erlide. It just stares back at me blankly. Not sure whether to persist, or try something else.

For what it´s worth - I will not consider erlang-mode - even if my life depended on it. I am a longtime Vim user, and I will not endanger my immortal soul for the sake of Sinan. ;^}

Answer (score 1):

[A]--create the sinan project in the workspace

[B]--open eclipse indigo

[C]--In eclipse create new erlang project with the same name as the one you created with sinan
     and in the same directory(workspace in this case)
[D]-- that's it,

otherwise import project, select general, file system, browse to your project 
and click ok and your good to go.
this should work for any language

Answer (score 0):

Create an Erlang project in Erlide (this will create the `.project` file and `.settings` directory for Eclipse), remove the created directory structure, and generate the Sinan directory structure? I don't have Sinan installed on this computer, but don't see any reason this wouldn't work.

Comment: tried it. It still didn't work for me. When I tried to import the projects (after adding .project files and settings dirs) it failed will NullRefException. Are you just using Erlide, or do you use some other build automation tool as well?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "It just stares back at me blankly"? What happens when you import the Sinan-structured project in erlide?

It should work, but maybe not automatically, I didn't tried it. Did you set the project directories in the properties dialog?

Comment: I mean that although I point the workspace at the root of the projects area that I generated with sinan, Erlide doesn't detect the projects beneath the source directory. I doesn't work if I point erlide at the lib dir either...

Comment: How does your project area look like? It works for me, but it is a little non-obvious, I will try to fix that. Note that there are two ways to import: the erlang import and the generic "import existing projects". The first doesn't need .project files, but works only for a single project at a time. The other searches recursively a dir for .project files and creates several at once, but you need to create the .settings/org.erlide.core.prefs files yourself.